# How to write data to process address space from kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, address-space

When a process is created by `do_execve`, I want to write some data somewhere (say 0x0100_0000)  such that after the process is run it can access that address to retrieve the data? How to achieve this task?

Comment: You can create a section in binary (or use existing). On exec was, when sections are loaded into memory fill it with appropriate values

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO). [Example](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-vdso-colonels-other-chicken) of using VDSO mechanism for own calls. The idea is to link userspace application and your code in kernel through special shared library. `gettimeofday` syscall is implemented in such way, what allows to reduce number of context switches.